# Removing Width and Height Attributes on Images added via Rich Text Editor

Tags: pipelines, richtext-editor

I have used the method seen [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1554/is-there-a-way-to-supress-rendering-width-and-height-attribs-using-fortis-image) to remove the Width and Height attributes on an image generated using the HTML Helpers in Sitecore, and it works perfectly.

Is there a way to apply this same functionality to an image that has been added via a Rich Text Editor?